# Connect to Azure Service Bus with Amqp over WebSockets using new Standard library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I am trying to send a message to my queue hosted in azure. 
My application communicates with the world through a proxy. 
I use the .Net Core 2.1 and the new the standard azure service bus nuget.
I need to use Amqp over web sockets through the port 443. Unfortunately I have not succeed with that. Is there anybody who implemented such a thing? Can anybody provide a code snippet on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance! Here is what I am trying:

```
var transportProvider = new AmqpTransportProvider();
var amqpSettings = new AmqpSettings
{ 
        RequireSecureTransport = true, TransportProviders = {transportProvider} 
};

var socketSettings = new WebSocketTransportSettings()
{
      Proxy = new WebProxy() {Address = new Uri("http://myproxy"), BypassProxyOnLocal = false},
      SubProtocol = "https",
      Uri = new Uri($"wss://{_azureConfiguration.NameSpace}"),
};

AmqpTransportInitiator transportIntInitiator = new AmqpTransportInitiator(amqpSettings, socketSettings);
var b = transportIntInitiator.ConnectAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), new TransportAsyncCallbackArgs());

ServiceBusConnection s = new ServiceBusConnection($"sb://{_azureConfiguration.NameSpace}", TransportType.AmqpWebSockets);
s.TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
s.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

var sender = new MessageSender(s, _azureConfiguration.QueueName);
string messageBody = $"Message";
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
await sender.SendAsync(message);
```

The code gets following error: Unable to connect to the remote server. Inner exception details: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

StackTrace:

System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1 messageList) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\Core\MessageSender.cs:line 562
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\RetryPolicy.cs:line 83
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\RetryPolicy.cs:line 105
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.SendAsync(IList`1 messageList) in C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\Core\MessageSender.cs:line 252

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: "...Unfortunately I have not succeed with that..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: I edited my post. Can you check again? Just to say that I have tried the simple version with QueueClient and it did not work.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and for functions Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 3.x (I used 3.4.0 and 3.0.4 respectively). 
Use the standard var messageSender = new MessageSender(queueConnectionString, queueName, RetryPolicy.Default);

Just change your servicebus connectionstring to

Endpoint=sb://yadayada.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SenderPolicy;SharedAccessKey=yadayada;**TransportType=AmqpWebSockets**

And it will use websockets/https and hence port 443.
Sorry did not get the proxy part working but was under the impression that if it is setup at the network level, it will autodetect and the above should work. There is also a relay through option. If I get it working I will update, but I originally found this post just trying to get the 443/ampqwebsockets to work.

Comment: were you able to get the proxy part working? I tried your suggestion and I am receiving this error `System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
`

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus with this, I was getting Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusCommunicationException:  ErrorCode: TimedOut' , i realised by looking at your comment about mentioning      TransportType to AmqpWebSockets to shift to websockets, thanks, this is working.

Comment: That saved my day. I could not figure it out because somehow the NSG was blocking it but I had no control to change it or view the logs. I didn't find any Microsoft documentation that said clearly which protocol is used and how to change it to websockets. Luckily saw this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this still working for anyone? The other answer suggests it no longer works, which is my experience. Not sure what to do :(

Comment: Using the ServiceBusClientOptions to set the _transport type_ to `AmqpWebSockets` works, and this answer which says to add query string to connection string also works. As of Sep 2023.

Answer (score 2):

Using the new package "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" you will find the TransportType=AmqpWebSockets parameter of the connection string is ignored.

To configure transport type you can do the following:

```
    var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions
    {
        TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
    });
```